# Android app, how to center align ImageView in a TableLayout cell programmatically

Tags: java, android

I've following code, within an Android app:

```
TableRow row = new TableRow(this);
TableRow.LayoutParams lp = new 
TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
lp.setMargins(0,5,0,0);
row.setLayoutParams(lp);
List<List<String>> cList2 = displayTemp.getCList2();
StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
List<String> lStr = cList2.get(0);
for (int ix = 0; ix < lStr.size(); ix++) {
    sb.append(lStr.get(ix));
    if (ix != lStr.size() - 1) {
        sb.append("\n");
    }
}
TextView tv = new TextView(this);
tv.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(0, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1.0f));
tv.setText(sb.toString());
tv.setTextSize(COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 20);
row.addView(tv);
byte[] decodedString = Base64.decode(cList2.get(1).get(0), Base64.DEFAULT);
Bitmap decodedByte = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(decodedString, 0,decodedString.length);
ImageView iView = new ImageView(this);
iView.setImageBitmap(decodedByte);
row.addView(iView);
tableLayout2.addView(row, rowNum);
rowNum++;
```

This displays a table row dynamically. My 2nd table cell is displayed with this code,

```
byte[] decodedString = Base64.decode(cList2.get(1).get(0), Base64.DEFAULT);
Bitmap decodedByte = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(decodedString, 0,decodedString.length);
ImageView iView = new ImageView(this);
iView.setImageBitmap(decodedByte);
row.addView(iView);
```

The image displayed in the 2nd cell is currently right aligned. I want to display this as center aligned in the cell. How can I do that?

Answer (score 2):

Add below line of code

```
lp.gravity = Gravity.CENTER;
```

Final code

```
TableRow.LayoutParams lp = new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
//rest of code
lp.gravity = Gravity.CENTER;
row.setLayoutParams(lp);
```

[Gravity](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Gravity.html) has below options.

Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL
Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
tv.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
row.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
```

OR

```
LayoutParams lp = new LayoutParams();
lp.gravity = Gravity.CENTER;
tv.setLayoutParams(lp);
row.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
```

There is no direct way to apply border on each cell but you can do it manually by using android:background="@drawable/cell_border" wherever you need it.

**cell_border.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape= "rectangle"  >
    <solid android:color="#000"/>
    <stroke android:width="1dp"  android:color="#ff9"/>
</shape>
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me. How can I show borders (of some thickness like few pixels) around each cell of the table, for easy visualization of alignment of the cell's children (like TextView or ImageView).

Comment: Updated the answer